# How to define an Model.all instance variable in the new action.

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a RESTful app in which I create movie summaries.

On my new page, I want to be able to see the titles of movies I've already created.

In my controller, I define both `@movies` and `@movie` in the new action.

```
  def new
    @movies = Movie.all
    @movie = Movie.new
  end
```

In my new view, I included data for @movies above the form

```
<% @movies.each do |movie| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= movie.name %></td>
    <td><%= movie.info %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
#My form starts here, under the table of movie info
```

This works when I go to the new action for the first time. However, when I redirect here from a failed `create`, I get `nil` for @movies.

Why is this, and how can I define @movies so that it works for redirected failed creations as well?

Comment: Can you post your code for your 'create' action?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the `create` action fails, you typically should not be using a `redirect_to` to point the browser back to the `new` action. Instead you should be simply calling `render :new` if the save fails.

When you `render` another action's view, the you need to make sure you're supplying that view with the variables it expects *(in your case that's `@movies` and `@movie`)*. The `new` action itself isn't being executed when `render :new` is called.

One way you can fix this is to remove the `@movies` assignment into a `before_filter`. This way it will be assigned before both the `:new` and `:create` action, guaranteeing it's availability whenever you render the `:new` action's view.

```
class MoviesController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :prepare_movies, only: [ :new, :create ]

  def new
    @movie = Movie.new
  end

  def create
    @movie = Movie.new(params[:movie])

    if @movie.save
      # success; redirect elsewhere
    else
      # failure; render the :new action's view
      render :new
    end
  end

  private

    def prepare_movies
      @movies = Movie.all
    end
end
```

Comment: Thanks @Deefor, that works perfectly. 
You explain that the `new` action isn't being executed with `render`. Then how does it know `@movie` without a before filter? Is it using the `@movie` from the create action?

Comment: Correct. Once you've submitted the form to `POST` to the `:create` action, **ignore** what the `:new` action has and is doing. In that `:create` action you've done some validation against `@movie`, it failed, and now you want to show the movie's form again (which happens to be in a file called `new.html.erb`. You want to include the errors in `@movie.errors`; this is why redirecting on a failure is typically not what you want to do. Instead, you call `render`, specifying the template name `:new` which will map to `new.html.erb`.

Comment: Important to also mention: You are explicitly telling rails how you want it to respond with that `render` call in your `:create` action. In the `:new` action you're not telling Rails how to respond, so it makes some assumptions for you. It assumes you'll want to provide an HTML response since that's how the request was made. It also assumes you want to use the template file named after the action - `app/views/movies/new.html.erb`. You could explicitly end your `:new` action with `render :new` too - Rails is just saving you some typing.

Comment: Thanks @Deefour, your explanation clarifies things a good bit for me. I ended up defining `@movies` in the `create` action in the `else` block if it doesn't save (instead of using the before_filter).